# Probabilistic solution of Hydrogen atom PDE?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, quantum-mechanics

I know that the Feynman-Kac formula gives a representation of the solutions of PDEs of the form
$$ \partial_t u = Lu + Vu$$
for some differential operator $L$ and a bounded potential $V$.

From the few quantum mechanics I studied I know that the wave function of an electron orbiting a fixed proton solves something like
$$Lu + Vu = 0$$
with $L \sim \Delta$ and $V \sim 1/|x|$.

Is there a Feller semigroup representation of such functions?

To me this problem seems more similar representing the solution of Laplace's equation
$$\begin{cases} \Delta u = 0 \text{ in } D
\\ u = f \text{ in } \partial D\end{cases}$$
using $u(x) = \mathbb{E}_x (f(X_\tau))$ where $\tau$ is the hitting time of $D^c$ of Broniwan motion $X_t$ starting from $x$.
In the Hydrogen atom case though the domain is all of $\mathbb{R}^3$, so no boundary condition is given, and the operator is not purely differential.

Comment: Good question. What does $\sim$ mean here, by the way? Is it just Asymptotic equivalence, i.e. $f \sim g$ if $f/g\to 1$ as $x\to \infty$?

Comment: Yes, "proportional to"